# How to serialize boost::accumulators::accumulator_set<>?

Tags: c++, boost

Everyone is concerned with protecting user privacy and their data these days. Being capable of performing statistical analysis on data without actually keeping data samples around longer than necessary is one firm step in the right direction.

The concept of accumulators in the *boost* library looks like ideal fit to make it happen.

> The **Accumulators Framework** is framework for performing incremental
>   calculations. Usage of the framework follows the following pattern:
>
> Users push data into the `accumulator_set<>` object one sample at a
>   time.
>
> The `accumulator_set<>` computes the requested quantities in the
>   most efficient method possible, resolving dependencies between
>   requested calculations, possibly caching intermediate results.

There is just one big catch. I have no idea how to serialize the accumulator instance so that I can persist it without needing to keep the sample data around between app launches.

**How to create an instance and** restore all necessary parameters needed for it to apply new samples and **continue its incremental computations**? I do not want to start from scratch nor do I want to keep the previous samples around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how accumulator_set works internally.

It doesn't keep the samples. In fact, if you just parameterized the set for the 'min' and 'max' stats, then the only *state* that is going to be kept is 2 values of the result type.

Some other stats keep more state (e.g. histograms, percentiles etc.).

Inasmuch as `accumulator_set<>` supports serialization in the first place¹, it should be fine with respect to sample retention.

¹ I haven't checked

---

**UPDATE**

Okay. I've looked at things for about an hour now and I see no reason to think that serialization is supported or easy to implement.

The most I've seen is that features are copyable.

But there's no allocator that you can tweak from the outside so you can't leverage say memory mapped files either.

That leads me to conclude that what you want is **not a feature** of the library. So, where the documentation intro:

> Boost.Accumulators is both a library for incremental statistical computation as well as an extensible ***framework for incremental calculation*** in general.

Then apparently we should take that to mean "incremental operations during the lifetime of an accumulator_set", not "incremental" as in resumable/persistable.

It does seem like a nice feature request that the library authors would like to help with?

Comment: Yes, it's good that it does not keep samples around. That is why i'd like to use it - it can perform incremental calculations based on previous samples having cached necessary intermediary results. But how to restore those intermediary results when constructing a new instance of the accumulator?

Comment: I don't think he wants to keep the samples at all, just the internal state necessary to "keep going". In other words, what he's actually asking is about the details to your footnote.

Comment: @Nir Added some thoughts; we could plink Eric Niebler for an expert opinion :)

Comment: @EricNiebler kind request for comment here (to make sure I'm not talking nonsense about "your" library). Cheers

Comment: @Sehe I really appreciate you taking time for this. Judging from your update and what Nir said, we are totally on the same page here on what the issue's about.

Comment: I am going to close this question and accept this answer since there is has been no follow-up. Until proven otherwise I'll have to accept the reality that what i'm looking for cannot be done currently.